# Pseudocode CamelCase excerise for AS Level Homework

Tags: pseudocode

I got given this task to do for homework... I get that the key task is the declaration of the array but I do not know how to separate each word the string in pseudocode and fill the empty spaces with "(Empty)" This is my code so far but I am stumped! This is dor AS Level BTW...

```
DECLARE CamelCaseArray : ARRAY[1:10] OF STRING
REPEAT
    PRINT “Enter a word starting with a capital letter: (eg. Word)”
UNTIL ??? /*I am stumped on what to do here, I do not have to use a REPEAT UNTIL BTW.*\
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is something that varies individually, so I don't know how much the following pseudo code would you find similar to the way you would imagine it.

First of all, I'm going to assume you have hard-coded (i.e. it's a fixed value) 10
elements in your array of strings.

I will also assume you are not able to use any pre-coded functions (like Split(' ')), but you are able to access a character in a string like you would in an array. (Example `STRING STR = "HELLO", STR[0] = 'H'`) and that you can compare a character literal ('C') to ASCII values (67).

Your pseudo code reminds me of COBOL by the way (Link provided) so maybe you could make some parallels to that.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/cobol_loop_statements.htm
(Look for PERFORM UNTIL)

```
    DECLARE CamelCaseArray : ARRAY[1:10] OF STRING
    DECLARE Input : STRING
    DECLARE CharCounter : INT >* This counter will be used to move thru the string as an array of characters
    DECLARE ArrayCounter : INT >* This will indicate an element of our array.
    CharCounter = 0 *> Set both to zero.
    ArrayCounter = 0 
    PRINT “Enter a string in CamelCase format>”
    READ Input FROM CONSOLE

    REPEAT 
    IF Input[CharCounter] > 64 AND Input[CharCounter] < 91 AND CharCounter IS NOT 0 >* Check whether our current character's ASCII values are between 64 and 91, which are the values for capital letters in the ASCII table AND if our character is not the first one in the string (since then we don't advance our array counter, we just add it instead.")
    CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] = CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] + Input[CharCounter] >* If it is, add it to the STRING element of the array
    ArrayCounter++ >* Increment our array counter.
    ELSE
    CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] = CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] + Input[CharCounter] >* Otherwise, just add the current character to the current array element
    END IF
    CharCounter++ >* Increment the character counter anyways, since we advance in the string.
    UNTIL CharCounter = LENGTH OF Input >* Do all this UNTIL our character counter is at the end of the string (I.E. It's length).
>* Now , filling the rest of the array with the (EMPTY) string:
IF ArrayCounter<LENGTH OF CamelCaseArray >* If our array counter is less than the array length after we went through our 10 words, we can fill the rest with (EMPTY)
REPEAT
CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] = "(EMPTY)" >* Fill current element with empty
ArrayCounter ++ >* Increment ArrayCounter
UNTIL ArrayCounter = LENGTH OF CamelCaseArray >* Do all this until we reach the end of our array.
END IF
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: YOU ARE INSANELY GOOD! I AM SPEECHLESS, I am able to use everything but staying as closest as possible to the official pseudocode... BTW Do you know what an A Level is?

Comment: @TFRFireboy Thank you! I guess the A level has something to do with the UK education system which I'm not familiar with... If there's anything else I could help with, tell me.

Comment: Do you know how I could put this in Python?

Mainly the seperating the CamelCase...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the python code you asked for

```
CamelCaseArray = [""]*10
CharCounter = 0
ArrayCounter = 0
Input = input("Enter a string in CamelCase format>")
Input= list(Input)
for i in range (0,len(Input)):
 if ord(Input[i]) > 64 and ord(Input[i]) < 91 and i != 0:
  ArrayCounter+=1
 CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] = CamelCaseArray[ArrayCounter] + Input[i]

if ArrayCounter < 10:
 ArrayCounter+=1
 for i in range (ArrayCounter,10):
  CamelCaseArray[i] = "(EMPTY)"

for i in range (0,10):
 print(CamelCaseArray[i])
```